# Show-ing functions used in QuickCheck properties

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I'm trying to write a [QuickCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck) property that takes one or more functions as input.  To keep things simple, consider a property to check that function composition is equivalent to successive function application, and a quick-and-dirty test driver:

```
import Test.QuickCheck

prop_composition :: (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Bool
prop_composition f g x = (f . g) x == f (g x)

main :: IO ()
main = quickCheck prop_composition
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't compile, because the inputs to a property need to implement `Show` so that QuickCheck can report what inputs caused the failure, but there's no `Show` implementation for functions:

```
Test.hs:10:7:
    No instance for (Show (Int -> Int))
      arising from a use of `quickCheck' at Test.hs:10:7-33
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show (Int -> Int))
    In the expression: quickCheck prop_composition
    In the definition of `main': main = quickCheck prop_composition
```

I've tried writing my own do-nothing instance of `Show` for functions...

```
instance Show (a -> b) where
    show _ = "[func]"
```

... which compiles, but triggers a warning with `-Wall`...

```
Test.hs:3:9: Warning: orphan instance: instance Show (a -> b)
```

... which makes me think there's a more correct way to do this.

My gut tells me the answer lies in the [`Test.QuickCheck.Function`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/latest/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck-Function.html) module, but it's undocumented, and I can't figure out just from looking at the type signatures what anything in there is for or how it's intended to be used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right `Test.QuickCheck.Function` is the right answer. 
You just change the types:

```
prop_composition       :: Fun Int Int -> Fun Int Int -> Int -> Bool
prop_composition f g x = ((apply f) . (apply g)) x == (apply f) ((apply g) x)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `import Text.Show.Functions` could also be used with keeping the original signature.